# Powershell: How to remove files that contain 2 or less lines

Tags: powershell, delete-file

My question is as follows: I have a main directory that contains several sub-directories, each of the sub directories contain several files than contain 1 or more lines. I would like to remove all files from these sub directories that contain 1 or 2 lines and leave all files that contain more than 2 lines.

What I have found/come up with until now:

```
$ActionTargetFolder = "\\networkfolder\"
$GetAllActionTargetSubFolders = Get-ChildItem $ActionTargetFolder -Recurse -Directory

Get-ChildItem $GetAllActionTargetSubFolders -Recurse -File  | Where-object  { 
    ((Get-Content $_| Measure-Object -line).lines) -le 2 } | Remove-Item -Force
```

No files are removed, no errors come up: what do I need to change?

I hope someone could help

**Example file content:**

**Filename 1: CustomernameA_20220820**

**Content file 1 (must not be removed, since it contains 4 lines):**

|Changed database context to 'ABCLog'.
|Identifier |2022-08-11 |Time   |Actions    |191    |ActionCompleted
|Identifier |2022-08-12 |Time   |Actions    |269    |ActionCompleted
|Identifier |2022-08-13 |Time   |Actions    |104    |ActionCompleted

**Filename 2:CustomernameA_20220827**

**Content file 2 (must not be removed, since it contains 3 lines):**

|Changed database context to 'ABCLog'.
|Identifier |2022-08-12 |Time   |Actions    |26 |ActionCompleted
|Identifier |2022-08-13 |Time   |Actions    |104    |ActionCompleted

So the general idea is to combine these files into one file, since they have duplicate data. Furthermore, as you can see for date 2022-08-12, the value is different: the value in the second line is always wrong and should therefore be removed. The first line contains the line 'Changed database context to 'ABCLog'.' and can also be removed. I can combine the files by skipping the first to lines and put the rest in one file, however, sometime the file does not contain a line with values: if I then skip 2 lines, my script keeps on processing (cannot cope with an empty file??).
Therefore, I want to remove all files that only have 1 or 2 lines in them: they will be made empty and are of no use to me.

Typical file that I want to be removed:

**Filename 3:CustomernameA_20220827**

**Content file 3 (must be removed, contains 2 lines):**

|Changed database context to 'ABCLog'.|
|Identifier |2022-08-12 |Time   |Actions    |26 |ActionCompleted

I hope I clarified it some more.

Comment: Would love to see sample files with to do figure out the differences.  Else, we have to consider vaguely and try to write a script.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Your edit with sample data doesn't help; in fact, it creates confusion by discussing requirements ("combine these files into one file, since they have duplicate data") that seem to be _incidental_ to your solution attempt. Leaving efficiency aside, there's no obvious problem with your solution attempt, so in the absence of an [mcve] it's unlikely that you'll get the help you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my approach would be like this

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\stackoverflow\" -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
$StreamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.fullname)
#Read FirstLine - do nothing
$StreamReader.ReadLine() 
#Read SecondLine - do nothing
$StreamReader.ReadLine() 
#Read ThirdLine - Remove File if Null
if ($StreamReader.ReadLine() -eq $null){
$StreamReader.Close()
Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName
}
}
```

Comment: I think User's solution is a good solution and this could work. I would only replace both $_.fullname by "$($_.fullname)" to account for possible spaces and other special characters in the filenames.

Comment: @ExcèsRefusé, you never need `"$(...)"` around an expression that by itself evaluates to a string. PowerShell does _not_ work like a POSIX-compatible shell such as Bash in this respect; that is, the expression value - say `$_.FullName` - is passed as-is, irrespective of what the value contains - be it spaces or other shell metacharacters.

Comment: @User: this works, thank you! All files containing 2 or less lines are removed.